# Update field inside nested array based on condition in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this structure in collection. i want to update "remark" to "Better" if "language" is "english".

```
{"Information":[{"id":"5245","details":[{"language":"english","remark":"good","status":"published"},{"language":"hindi","remark":"good","status":"published"},{"language":"arabic","remark":"good","status":"published"}]}],"name":"saroj","company":"visa"}
```

i am able to get the particular section of data from db based on language

```
db.getCollection("containts").aggregate([
// Filter possible documents
{ "$match": {"$and": [{ "Information.id": "1" },{ "name": "saroj" }]}},

// Unwind the array to denormalize
{ "$unwind": "Information" },
{ "$unwind": "Information.details" },

// Match specific array elements
{ "$match": { "Information.detail.language": "english" } },

// Group back to array form
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "details": { "$push": "Information.details" }
}}])
```

Output:

```
{  "details": [{
  "language": "english",
  "remark": "good",
  "status": "published"
}]}
```

But i am unable to update "remark" based on "language"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arrayFilters` to update the element inside the array if you are using **mongodb 3.6** and above.
I have used the same array that you have mentioned in the question above and tested the below query which returns the updated document.

```
db.collectionName.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "Information.id": "5245", "name": "saroj"},
    { $set : {"Information.$[outer].details.$[elem].remark" : "better"}},
    {   
        returnNewDocument : true,
        arrayFilters: [{"elem.language": "english"},{ "outer.id": "5245"}]
    }
 )
```

you can get a detailed explanation about `arrayFilters` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

Aditionally to get the updated document as a result, in mongoose you can use `{new : true}` instead of `returnNewDocument: true` (this is used in mongodb shell).

Comment: can i use upsert:true here to insert if the searched data is not available ?
i tried its not working can you suggest soemthing